# use a small matrix to generate a larger matrix by concatenating it again and again

Tags: matlab

I have a 40x43 matrix and I would like to use this matrix a building block to generate larger matrix.
I want to generate a structure like the image attached and the building block is the 40x43 matrix. I tried using [A zeros(20,43); zeros(20,43) A] but as I had guessed, the horzcat did't work. I would ideally like to use this block  1000 times to extend the structure of matrix. Could anyone tell me an efficient way to concatenate the small matrix?

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html).  This performs what is known as the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) such that for two matrices `A` and `B`, the result is:

[image]

In this case, we can replicate what you want exactly by setting `A` to be the identity matrix of size 1000 x 1000 and `B` to be the matrix you want to replicate. However, to promote computational savings and memory usage, make sure you use the **sparse** version of the identity matrix.  This will convert the output matrix to `sparse` form.  If you want to replicate this 1000 times, you are creating a 40000 x 43000 matrix and this requires 13.76 GB of memory and you probably don't have enough memory available for this matrix.  Since most of the elements are zero, use the `sparse` version instead:

```
N = 1000;
B = kron(speye(N), A);
```

Comment: I had to modify your code a little bit to get the exact same output but it significantly made my work simpler. thanks!